# how to group same vector of normal in image (python)

Tags: python, opencv, normals

I want to separate wall and floor. Now, I have a depth image and find surface normal in depth image. I want to group same vector of normal and convert image into binary.

[image]

The follow code is how I find surface normal.

```
    d_im = depth_image.astype("float64")

    zy, zx = np.gradient(d_im)  
    normal = np.dstack((-zx, -zy, np.ones_like(d_im)))

    n = np.linalg.norm(normal, axis=2)

    normal[:, :, 0] /= n
    normal[:, :, 1] /= n
    normal[:, :, 2] /= n

    # offset and rescale values to be in 0-255
    normal += 1
    normal /= 2

    cv2.imshow("Normal Image", normal[:, :, ::-1])
```

I want to get the normal vector from wall. How can I do ? Thanks a lot

depth_image file:

http://www.wikiupload.com/20D8UHUU58FTP2S

How can I get z vector in program?

Comment: Can you upload the `depth_image` binary data using `np.save()` and attach a link to this thread? I would need to play with the input depth image data a little bit to come out with some solution ?

Comment: @ZdaR depth_image uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy naive solution would be to use the z component in the normal vector with some threshold 
becaus the normal vector is normalized the z component of the floor would have value close to 1 while for the wall will have value close to 0 
so a threshold of 0.5 might give good start 
probably you would need a denoising method after that

Comment: sorry for asking silly question, can I get the z component in program?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I checked that the value of normal[:,:,2] between floor and wall almost in the same range, but zx will always be positive if vector point upward. however, I find some of zx of wall is positive too, I have no idea to classify wather it is wall or floor in this case.